# Rails server not starting and giving messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, terminal

My current ruby version is ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]
and rails version is 4.0.0

Every time I run any rails command I get following message first:

```
/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-     1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:216: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
```

I was able to create new rails app, but when I start the server using

```
rails server
```

or

```
rails s
```

I get following message

```
/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:216: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `rescue in execute_if_updated': Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: #<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x007f9019eec2c0 @paths=["/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/RubyRails/profile/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007f9019d795c8>]> (RuntimeError)
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/RubyRails/profile/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/RubyRails/profile/config.ru:3:in `require'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/RubyRails/profile/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/RubyRails/profile/config.ru:in `new'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/RubyRails/profile/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
from /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I can see that server hasn't started due to some errors. But I'm unable to comprehend what's happening here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had typo in my routes.rb
Fixed it and it resolved my server issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try recursive *chmod*

```
chmod -R o-w /usr/local/
```

Comment: what permissions on your home folder?

Comment: I did `ls -ld /usr/local` and this is what I get `drwxr-xr-x@ 15 aniruddhabarapatre1 502 510 Dec 18 22:24 /usr/local`